# Win 10 S mode: did not meet the Custom 1 signing level requirements or violated code integrity policy

Tags: desktop-bridge

I have developed an application that needs DLLs to run that go with it and I need the application to be Win 10 S compatible. When I run the application (EncLock) in Win 10 S mode (using test policies described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-test-windows-s) I get Code Integrity event logs

`EncLock.exe attempted to load some.dll that did not meet the Custom 1 signing level requirements or violated code integrity policy (Policy ID:{a244370e-44c9-4c06-b551-f6016e563076}).`

I have the app associated with the Microsoft app store and I do have the StoreKey.pfx which I used to Digitally Sign all the DLLs involved and the EXE. However, when I install the app on my local machine and run it while running the Win 10 S test Audit mode policy I am still getting the `...did not meet the Custom 1 signing level requirements...` events in the Event Logger.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had to purchase a signing certificate to sign all the executables of EncLock including the DLLs shipped with it. Had to purchase the signing cert from one of the companies Microsoft trusts. There are a few of them but I went with Comodo. Only then was EncLock accepted on Microsoft app store.